# quartz 1.6 scheduler is not working after migrating Java application from 10g to 11g

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, quartz-scheduler

I used `quartz 1.6` scheduler with `Java` application built in `10g` technology from `Oracle` using `Jdeveloper 10g` as IDE.

The application is working fine with the mentioned technology. But, After migrating the application to `11g` technology the `quartz scheduler` is not working any more. The `Weblogic` server used to deploy this migrated technology is `Weblogic 10.3`

---

**----------------Update--------------------**

The application works fine from Jdeveloper but when I deploy it on the external weblogic server I the scheduler is simply not working

Comment: What errors do you get? "Not working" is not descriptive enough for anyone to help you... There are lots of examples out there of quartz 1.8+ working with weblogic 10.3 - for instance http://zeosaho.blogspot.com/2013/07/quartz-executes-twice-on-weblogic.html

Comment: @castling check updates if you have time